# Is it possible to use kAudioUnitSubType_VoiceProcessingIO without automatic gain control (mode = measurement)

Tags: ios, avaudiosession, audiounit

I am trying to use the `kAudioUnitSubType_VoiceProcessingIO` for the signal processing. But I want to disable all automatic voodoo like AGC. I am trying to do it like this

```
        [sessionInstance setMode:AVAudioSessionModeMeasurement error:&error];
```

and

```
        AudioComponentDescription desc;
        desc.componentType         = kAudioUnitType_Output;
        desc.componentSubType      = kAudioUnitSubType_VoiceProcessingIO;
        desc.componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;
        desc.componentFlags        = 0;
        desc.componentFlagsMask    = 0;
```

But when I log the session mode, I see it being reset to `AVAudioSessionModeVoiceChat`.

When using the default `kAudioUnitSubType_RemoteIO` I see the mode staying at `AVAudioSessionModeMeasurement`.

**Is there a way to disable all automatic stuff (like AGC, filter) when using the VoiceProcessingIO?**

Answer (score 0):

Try the below snippet, where `agcIsOn` is your boolean and `audioUnit` is the `AudioUnit` object you have.

```
            var uValue: Int32 = agcIsOn ? 1 : 0;
            // 0 turns off AGC
            // 1 turns on AGC
            let status = AudioUnitSetProperty(audioUnit, kAUVoiceIOProperty_VoiceProcessingEnableAGC,
                                          kAudioUnitScope_Global, AudioEngine.kInputBus,
                                          &uValue, memorySize(of: uValue))
```

Comment: Thanks.. i have tried that but when i record the buffers, i can see that AGC is still applied. meanwhile i have found out the the VoiceProcessingIO is highly uncontrollable. So the system can just decide what happens without prior notification

Comment: I think you need to set this property before starting the audio unit, i.e. before `AudioOutputUnitStart()`. If you need to set it midway, you'll have to stop it, set the property, then start again.